# mysql PDO update query errors with 1062 Duplicate entry '4146' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, duplicates, sql-update

I have a mysql database and the query is built in PHP.  The query is a traditional update query, yet when it runs, I get an error that states 1062 Duplicate entry '4146' for key 'PRIMARY'.  This seems counter intuitive, as I am trying to update the row 4146, I am not sure why it complains.

I have other PDO statements that work fine.  I've tried specifying various PDO::PARAM's, and have googled for about an hour without finding a good answer.

Here is the base sql statement, followed by the error:

```
UPDATE tmp_event set
    event_no=:event_no,
    artist_no=:artist_no,
    squality_no=:squality_no, 
    studio_album=:studio_album, 
    album=:album, 
    concert_display=:concert_display, 
    collection_display=:collection_display, 
    interview=:interview, 
    complete=:complete, 
    tradeable=:tradeable, 
    event_date=:event_date, 
    unqualified=:unqualified, 
    event_day=:event_day, 
    event_month=:event_month, 
    event_year=:event_year, 
    comments=:comments, 
    venue_no=:venue_no, 
    media_no=:media_no
```

> PDO Exception: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4146' for key 'PRIMARY' in /media/web/www/2.4/admin/submit.php:969 Stack trace: #0 /media/web/www/2.4/admin/submit.php(969): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}

Here is the PHP code that does the work:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tmp_event set event_no=:event_no, artist_no=:artist_no, squality_no=:squality_no, studio_album=:studio_album, album=:album, concert_display=:concert_display, collection_display=:collection_display, interview=:interview, complete=:complete, tradeable=:tradeable, event_date=:event_date, unqualified=:unqualified, event_day=:event_day, event_month=:event_month, event_year=:event_year, comments=:comments, venue_no=:venue_no, media_no=:media_no";

$handle = $link -> prepare($sql);
$handle->bindparam(':event_no',$event_no, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$handle->bindparam(':artist_no',$artist_no, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$handle->bindparam(':squality_no',$squality_no, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$handle->bindparam(':studio_album',$studio_album, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$handle->bindparam(':album',$album, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$handle->bindparam(':concert_display',$concert_display, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$handle->bindparam(':collection_display',$collection_display, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$handle->bindparam(':interview',$interview, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$handle->bindparam(':complete',$complete, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$handle->bindparam(':tradeable',$tradeable, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$handle->bindparam(':event_date',$event_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$handle->bindparam(':unqualified',$unqualified, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$handle->bindparam(':event_day',$event_day, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$handle->bindparam(':event_month',$event_month, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$handle->bindparam(':event_year',$event_year, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$handle->$bindparam(':comments',$comments, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$handle->bindparam(':venue_no',$venue_no, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$handle->bindparam(':media_no',$media_no, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$handle->execute();
```

I expect the query to execute the update without error.  Thanks for any insight you might have!

Comment: I'm assuming event_no is your PK. try  `UPDATE tmp_event set  artist_no=:artist_no, squality_no=:squality_no, studio_album=:studio_album, album=:album, concert_display=:concert_display, collection_display=:collection_display, interview=:interview, complete=:complete, tradeable=:tradeable, event_date=:event_date, unqualified=:unqualified, event_day=:event_day, event_month=:event_month, event_year=:event_year, comments=:comments, venue_no=:venue_no, media_no=:media_no WHERE event_no = :event_no,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has no WHERE clause so it will attempt to update every row in the table. As soon as it does so on the first row it tries to set the `event_no` column and finds it has a duplicate.

Add a WHERE clause to the query, and don't attempt to set `event_no`

```
UPDATE tmp_event set artist_no=:artist_no, squality_no=:squality_no, studio_album=:studio_album, album=:album, concert_display=:concert_display, collection_display=:collection_display, interview=:interview, complete=:complete, tradeable=:tradeable, event_date=:event_date, unqualified=:unqualified, event_day=:event_day, event_month=:event_month, event_year=:event_year, comments=:comments, venue_no=:venue_no, media_no=:media_no WHERE event_no = :event_no
```

Comment: LULZ i like how you copy and pasted my comment as your answer, but didn't even bother to up vote my comment.

Comment: @bassxzero Your comment makes no attempt to explain the problem, and thus isn't worthy of an upvote. The part you think is copy pasted can only be the query, which would come out the same whatever. You could have posted your own answer, but chose not to. Unless you think there's something wrong with my answer I'd ask you to retract your downvote.

Comment: @bassxzero The fix is so obvious - It's quite possible that someone would write the exactly same query as in your comment without reading it. Also you have a syntax error in your query (`,` at the end). And please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288849/5563083

Comment: Thanks redd herring, easy catch.  No idea what happened to my query.  Appreciate the second set of eyes, as I was too close.